# Борьба с дублированием кода

Tags: php, mvc

Опытные коллеги, подскажите.
Я разрабатываю небольшой движок для сайта на основе MVC.
У меня есть набор контроллеров, моделей и вьюшек, все как полагается. Но есть проблема с дублированием методов. 
Конкретнее -  у меня есть контроллер UserController у которого есть экшн checkUser, который обращается к модели User::checkUserHash которая просто вытаскивает строку пользователя из базы по id куки пользователя.
Вот код метода сheckUserHash модели User

```
public static function checkUserHash($cookie_id)

{

   # соединение с БД 
   $db = DB::getConnection();

   # Проверяем хэш куки на совпадение значение в БД
   $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '".$cookie_id."' LIMIT 1");
   $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $data = $query->fetch();

   return $data;
}
```

И у меня есть контроллер LoginController у которого тоже есть экшн checkUser который обращается к модели Login::checkLogUserHash , так вот в методе Login::checkLogUserHash мне нужен абсолютно такой же функционал, как и в методе User::checkUserHash, получается два одинаковых метода с разным именем.

Конечно можно просто подключить файл модели User к контроллеру LoginController и использовать его методы, но насколько я понимаю это противоречит философии MVC . Что у каждого контроллера должна быть своя модель и вьюшка.

Подскажите как быть?

Comment: Можно просто для начала вынести повторяющийся код в отдельный файл, Файл подключается к обеим контроллерам.

Comment: Да в php есть полная поддержка ооп.  То есть решение - это создать AppController  в котором будет общий функионал, а все остальные контроллеры наследовать от него. Правильно?

Comment: Я надеюсь, вы перед вызовом этого метода всегда проверяете, что в `$cookie_id` находится именно id пользователя, а не, например строка вроде `' OR 1=1`?

Comment: Да конечно , проверяю, а то уволят еще)))

Comment: @Dmitriy, можно трейты использовать для одинакового функционала в разных классах http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: Трейты - эврика!!! они же для того и придуманы. Считаю вопрос закрытым. Спасибо большое Visman!

Comment: @Dmitriy а мне трейты напоминают некий костыль, которым попытались заткнуть то, что не смогли реализовать стандартным подходом.. Вещь конечно прикольная, но....Имхо тут надо действовать на уровне ООП, паттернов, .............а Utility классы обычно делают статическими со статик методами..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller:

```
    <?php
    class Controller {
         public function checkLogUserHash()
         {
            // \Login::checkLogUserHash();
         }
    }
```

UserController

```
    <?php
    class UserController extends Controller {
    }
```

LoginController

```
    <?php
    class LoginController extends Controller {
    }
```

далее думаю все понятно:

```
    $userController = new UserController();
    $userController->checkLogUserHash();
    $loginController = new LoginController();
    $LoginController->checkLogUserHash();
```

Comment: Спасибо, тоже вариант, но я решил использовать трейты